# Disable authentication for OPTIONS requests in Tomcat

Tags: ajax, tomcat, authentication, cors, preflight

I have an API protected by basic auth. When I want to make AJAX requests against the API, the browser send an OPTIONS request which doesn't carry the Authorization header so it gets rejected and thus my AJAX call is not allowed by the browser.

I tried to configure Tomcat to not authenticate OPTIONS requests but I don't manage to get it work.

Someone to help me to get it works?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I had to specify the list of HTTP methods on which the authentication was applied. Default is to apply on all methods.

Comment: Where did you supply the list? To the AJAX call or to Tomcat?

Comment: To Tomcat configuration ;)

Comment: Where in tomcat did you edit that configuration?